# How to save table filters/page after changing route?

Tags: angular

I've got a table of reports and custom filters, pagination there. Then I change route to /:reportId. After I navigate back to the table,  filters/paging are reset. How to save that on route changing only when I go back from report route(if from others, reset filters). How to hook that when I came exactly from report route?

P.S. I subscribe to service http request in ngOnInit() in the tableComponent

Comment: How many parameters for filter the data?

Comment: Paging, sort(array), filetype

Comment: So take that params in the URL and while clicking back you will get these params

Comment: Share the stackblitz if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your filter and sort settings in variable in a service

```
let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
    queryParams: { 
        'page': currentPage,
        'sortBy': 'date',
        'filter': true
    }
};
```

Then use that variable with navigation

```
// Navigate to the table component with extras
this.router.navigate(['/table'], navigationExtras);
```

And use them to set your table

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        // update the table
    });
}
```

The pro is that the same URL will give you the same table filter/sort state, which might be useful in some cases, the con is that you will have to deal with long URLs as you add parameters.

If you are looking for a more elaborate solution, definitely check out NgRx (as mentioned by @hohnzy)

Answer (score 3):

I would use some kind of state management ([NgRx](https://ngrx.io/), [NGXS](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/)), or you can store applied filters, page in a service.

Comment: Thanks for recommendation, I'll try. Is NgRx something like Redux in ReactJS?

Comment: @NateRiver yes exactly

Answer (score 0):

You must fit any page store the information in the localStorage, for example:

```
filterData: {page1: {Paging: '', sort: [], filetype: ''}, page2: {Paging: '', sort: [], filetype: ''}}
```

Comment: I only need to save that when I go back to table from report route. What about resetting when going from another route? How to hook that?

Answer (score 0):

use parent container component for table and table item.

```
{
    path: 'table',
    component: ContainerComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: TableComponent,
      },
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: TableItemComponent,
      }
    ]
  },
```

Save filters in TableComponent's ngOnDestroy(). Reset filters in ContainerComponent's ngOnDestroy(). Keep data in additional service.